# Button element not displaying text value

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8 (Metro App Development)
2. Left pane; select JavaScript as the language. Right pane; select Blank template
3. Click OK
4. Insert: `<button name="printbutton" value="Print" />` into *default.html*
5. Debug (<kbd>F5</kbd>)

**The problem:**
When I start a brand new HTML5 + JavaScript Windows Store application, and add just 1 element, without making any further changes to the solution, the text value of the button element (`value="Print"`), does not appear.

---

Why is this, and have I done something wrong? See below for a screenshot:

[image]

I have tried setting the `Button` element's text color to White (since the background is Dark), by adding `style="color:white"` to the `Button` element, but this did not have any effect at all.

Comment: Check your button font color ?

Comment: It seems that the Button element cannot be self-closing, since changing it to `<button>Print</button>` is now displaying its text value.

Comment: Thanks, @Devang, but as stated in the question, I had already given it a color that should be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<button name="printbutton" value="Print" style="color:white;">Print</button>
```

Comment: I m glad that my answer help you.